# Maximum width possible inside a container div

Tags: css

I am using skeleton css framework and i need some divs to occupy the maximum width possible,something like how SO does in the div holding the search input box.I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pRmus/1/ showing a simple div i made

```
.all-width{
    background-color:pink;
    }
```

Since i am displaying this div inside the container and the container width is 940px,the width cannot cover all the width the browser offers.Is there a solution i can i use to get what i want?.I was thinking z-index on that div,but i am not so sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the pink bar outside of container. Make a wrapper around an individual container, so this wrapper can really have 100% width.

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Y5mB6/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sixteen columns">
        <h1 class="remove-bottom" style="margin-top: 40px">Skeleton</h1>
        <h5>Version 1.2</h5>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class="container">            
        <div class="sixteen columns">
            <p>hello world</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="one-third column">
        <h3>About Skeleton?</h3>
...
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    background-color:pink;      
}
```

Comment: I had tried a similar solution but outside the very first container,it worked but yours is better since i can use it inside like in my breadcrumbs div.In your fiddle,the pink div extends beyond the container but not far enough if you see it outside jsfiddle.

Comment: JSFiddle restricts it that way, that's just part of how JSFiddle works. Try it on your website and see. It should work fine. Currently, the wrapper div assumes the width of its parent. If the HTML you gave has no other parent HTML elements, then the wrapper will take on 100% browser screen width.

Comment: I believe you.The css files i linked had issues.It now works as you said it would when i use the original skeleton 1.2 css files.Thanks.